# LI for Form - Alignment of Input text boxes

Tags: html, css

How can I align this code:
CSS:

```
input {
border: none;
}

input.name {
color: #f39200;
background:  url('../images/name.png') no-repeat left top;
width: 368px;
height: 48px;
padding-top: 1px;

padding-left: 100px;
font-size: 24px;
}
input.company {
    vertical-align: middle;
color: #f39200;
background:  url('../images/company.png') no-repeat left top;
width: 368px;
height: 48px;
padding-top: 0px;

padding-left: 140px;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" style="list-style-type: none; width: 400px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/sent" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="name" value="" />      
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="text" name="company" class="company" value="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I want to align them next to each other. So it will look something like this:

http://dflzqrzibliy5.cloudfront.net/images3/contact-form-generator.png

The first two are next to each other the others are not.. etc..

Comment: You can use `table` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `float:left;` and `display: inline-block;`. And you should check the `width` of the `form` and the `width + padding` of the `input` fields.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kLVL/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}